# Ignore path does not exist in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I want ignore the paths that generate the Error:

> 'Path does not exist'

when I read parquet files with pyspark. For example  I have a list of paths:

```
list_paths = ['path1','path2','path3']
```

and read the files like:

```
dataframe = spark.read.parquet(*list_paths)
```

but the path `path2` does not exist. In general, I do not know which path does not exits, so I want ignore `path2` automatically. How can I do it and obtain only one dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hadoop FS API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) to check if the files exist before you pass them to `spark.read`:

```py
conf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path


filtered_paths = [p for p in list_paths if Path(p).getFileSystem(conf).exists(Path(p))]

dataframe = spark.read.parquet(*filtered_paths)
```

Where `sc` is the SparkContext.

Comment: Using private methods/modules such as `_jsc` doesn't looks like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @blackbishop's answer, you can further use [Hadoop pattern strings](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-) to check for files/objects before loading them.

It's also worth noting that [`spark.read.load()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.load.html) accepts lists of path strings.

```py
from functools import partial
from typing import Iterator
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


def iterhadoopfiles(spark: SparkSession, path_pattern: str) -> Iterator[str]:
    """Return iterator of object/file paths that match path_pattern."""
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    FileUtil = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil
    Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
    hadoop_config = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
    p = Path(path_pattern)
    return (
        str(x)
        for x in FileUtil.stat2Paths(
            p.getFileSystem(hadoop_config).globStatus(p)
        )
    )


def pathnotempty(spark: SparkSession, path_pattern: str) -> bool:
    """Return true if path matches at least one object/file."""
    try:
        next(iterhadoopfiles(spark, path_pattern))
    except StopIteration:
        return False
    return True


paths_to_load = list(filter(partial(pathnotempty, spark), ["file:///*.parquet"]))
spark.read.format('parquet').load(paths_to_load)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do

```py
existing_paths = [path for path in list_paths if os.path.exists(path)]
dataframe = spark.read.parquet(*existing_paths)
```

Comment: I can't use this solution because the server only allow access to the data with pyspark or sql, os show always  "path doesn't exist". The solution require the use of pyspark